# Taylor Series. Reusing an approximation of a function

Tags: functions, approximation, taylor-expansion, mathematical-modeling

I have this function, $e^{-x}$ bounded between 0 and 1500 and I have an approximation by Taylor Series of the same function bounded between 0 and 0.5. I would like to express my function $e^{-x}$ bounded between 0 and 15oo in terms of the last approximation I described, what is bounded between 0 and 0.5.
Does anyone know how I can do it?
Thank you.

NOTE: This question is related with [Development of a hardware arquitecture for a particular algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14206/development-of-a-specific-hardware-architecture-for-a-particular-algorithm)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Development of a specific hardware architecture for a particular algorithm. Modelling fuctions by Taylor Series.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/development-of-a-specific-hardware-architecture-for-a-particular-algorithm-model)

Answer (score 3):

Where is the Taylor series for (0,1500) centered?  If at zero, it is the same Taylor series as for (0,0.5).  But you really don't want a Taylor series for (0,1500)-it would take an enormous number of terms for any reasonable accuracy.  [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nrbook.com/c/) (chapters 5 and 6) and all other numerical analysis books have suggestions for better models.  [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_69.htm) has a polynomial fit over (0,1) that is much more accurate than you need.  Given what you had in the previous question, you can't represent $\exp(-x)$ for $x$ much over 11 because you will underflow.

Comment: If I were in his shoes, I'd do scaling and squaring: for positive argument, keep dividing by 2 until it's small enough, evaluate a Padé approximant of appropriate order, and square the result of that an appropriate number of times, and then reciprocate.

Comment: (Answer to "Where is the Taylor series for (0,1500) centered?"): I was thinking about two possibilities. One, to use the maclaurin series, the other, would be to chose a middle point in the bound, for the bound (0,1500), I would chose as middle point, 750.

Comment: @Peterstone: Those are both possibilities.  The middle point will give better accuracy, as the ends of the interval are not so far away.  But can you fit exp(-1500) in your data type without underflow?  Even exp(-15)?